# Line graph for graphic in R?

Tags: r, csv, graph, linegraph

I have a csv in R which has the following table:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
        "Pool 1" = c("F1a", "R1a", "F2a", "R2a"),
        "Start Pool 1" = c("10", "20", "25", "35"), 
        "Pool 2" = c("F1b", "R1b", "F2b", "R2b"),
        "Start Pool 2" = c("15", "21", "23", "35"), 
        stringsAsFactors = F,check.names=FALSE)
```

| Pool 1 | Start Pool 1 | Pool 2 | Start Pool 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| F1a | 10 | F1b | 15 |
| R1a | 20 | R1b | 21 |
| F2a | 25 | F2b | 23 |
| R2a | 35 | R2b | 35 |

I want to create a graph in R which looks like this: [image: Final graph goal]

Comment: Would you please give more detailed information? For example, can you clarify what you want your `x-axis` to be etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your labels for Pool 2 is wrong, should be R1b instead

If you don't want to use any package, and have only 2 lines, you can build it up slowly by specifying a blank plot with `plot(NULL...)` , then you will place one line on `y=1`, the other on `y=2` and add the points, text based on these coordinates:

```
plot(NULL,xlim=c(10,35),ylim=c(0,3),xaxt="n",yaxt="n",
bty="n",xlab="",ylab="")
abline(h=1:2,col="#c0fefc")
points(x = df1[,"Start Pool 1"], y = rep(2,nrow(df1)),
pch=20,cex=2,col="#77acf1")
text(x = df1[,"Start Pool 1"], y = rep(2.5,nrow(df1)),
labels = df1[,"Pool 1"])
points(x = df1[,"Start Pool 2"], y = rep(1,nrow(df1)),
pch=20,cex=2,col="#77acf1")
text(x = df1[,"Start Pool 2"], y = rep(1.5,nrow(df1)),
labels = df1[,"Pool 2"])
axis(side=2,at=1:2,labels=c("Pool2","Pool1"),las=2,col=NA,col.ticks = 1)
```

[image]

Else use `ggplot2` :

```
df = data.frame(
       label = c(df1[,"Pool 1"],df1[,"Pool 2"]),
       value = c(df1[,"Start Pool 1"],df1[,"Start Pool 2"]),
       pool = rep(c("Pool1","Pool2"),each=nrow(df1))
       )

ggplot(df,aes(x=value,y=pool,label=label)) + 
geom_point(size=4,col="#77acf1") + 
geom_text(nudge_y=0.2) + 
theme_minimal() + 
xlab("") + ylab("") +
theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
axis.text.x = element_blank())
```

[image]